# OCaml: Unbound module from parent directory in toplevel

Tags: module, ocaml, loading, ocaml-toplevel

I'm trying to load a module from a parent directory into the top level interpretor.

```
#load "../Syntax.cmo";;
open Syntax

let foo = bar
```

Where bar is in Syntax. I have module Syntax in the parent directory. Loading module Syntax does not cause any problems, but the open line throws an error:

```
Error: Unbound module Syntax
```

I have also tried removing the open:

```
#load "../Syntax.cmo";;
let foo = Syntax.bar
```

But that gives me the same error as Syntax is in the parent directory.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use relative paths, instead use `#directory` directive:

```
#directory "..";;
#load "Syntax.cmo";;
let foo = Syntax.bar;;
```

Even better, define your library using oasis, or some other high-level tools, and use `#require` to load your libraries, instead of tackling with low-level directives.

Comment: Thank you for you response.
I tried it out, and it though it stopped with the "Unbound module Syntax" error, it gave me a new "Unbound value Syntax.bar" error.

Comment: that's just mean that your `Syntax` module doesn't define or export `bar` value.

Comment: but the module Syntax does indeed contain bar.
It has let bar a = a

EDIT: never mind, it was a compilation error of Syntax, which I had not caught. Now it works. Thanks! :)